# R ggplot stacking not showing lines no chart

Tags: r

I want to plot the 4 columns of a matrix and have the x-axis say (1,2,3,4). I have provided a simple example you can run.

```
require("reshape")
require("ggplot2")

a<-rbind(.493,.537,.50,.462)
b<-rbind(.846,-.117,-.349,-.385)
c<-rbind(-.181,.0657,.135,-.719)
d<-rbind(-.09,.51,-.77,.34)

   me<- cbind(a,b,c,d)
data<-c(me[,1], me[,2], me[,3], me[,4])
description<-rep(    c("PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4"), each=NROW(me)  )
d<- cbind(data, description)
ax <- rep(    cbind(seq(from= 1, to = 4, by =1)), NROW(me)  )
 stacked <- data.frame(d , xaxis= ax )  
stacked

ggplot(data=stacked, aes( x = xaxis,  y=data, colour=description))   +   geom_line()
```

The problem is that there should be 4 lines showing on the chart but it is blank.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `stacked <- data.frame(value = me, ...` rather than `value = d`?

Comment: Now the problem is the lines are not showing up. Any ideas? TY

Comment: `cbind`ing `data` and `description` to get (the new) `d` makes a matrix and since a matrix has only one type, `data` is converted to a string (notice y axis is categorical, not continuous). Note also warning you get which hints at why lines don't show up. Make your (second) definition of `d` a `data.frame` call instead of `cbind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are converting your numeric values to character strings when you use `cbind` to create the matrix you call `d`.  You are making it much harder than it is. Going back to your starting matrix `me` (simpler way specify the starting matrix rather than creating the steps you had; got it using `dump("me", "")`)

```
me <-
structure(c(0.493, 0.537, 0.5, 0.462, 0.846, -0.117, -0.349, 
-0.385, -0.181, 0.0657, 0.135, -0.719, -0.09, 0.51, -0.77, 0.34
), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

You are using "PC1", "PC2", to identify the columns, so include that in the matrix directly

```
colnames(me) <- c("PC1", "PC2", "PC3", "PC4")
```

Now `me` looks like

```
> me
       PC1    PC2     PC3   PC4
[1,] 0.493  0.846 -0.1810 -0.09
[2,] 0.537 -0.117  0.0657  0.51
[3,] 0.500 -0.349  0.1350 -0.77
[4,] 0.462 -0.385 -0.7190  0.34
```

The rows don't have names, but are just indexed counts which match exactly what you want for `xaxis` later. Now just melt this:

```
library("reshape2")
stacked <- melt(me)
```

which looks like

```
> stacked
   Var1 Var2   value
1     1  PC1  0.4930
2     2  PC1  0.5370
3     3  PC1  0.5000
4     4  PC1  0.4620
5     1  PC2  0.8460
6     2  PC2 -0.1170
7     3  PC2 -0.3490
8     4  PC2 -0.3850
9     1  PC3 -0.1810
10    2  PC3  0.0657
11    3  PC3  0.1350
12    4  PC3 -0.7190
13    1  PC4 -0.0900
14    2  PC4  0.5100
15    3  PC4 -0.7700
16    4  PC4  0.3400
```

and the columns are of the appropriate type

```
> str(stacked)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Var1 : int  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ Var2 : Factor w/ 4 levels "PC1","PC2","PC3",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ value: num  0.493 0.537 0.5 0.462 0.846 -0.117 -0.349 -0.385 -0.181 0.0657 ...
```

The column names are different than what you had in your `stacked`, but they are all there. The graphing call is then just

```
ggplot(stacked, aes(x=Var1, y=value, colour=Var2)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your  `data` variable is factor not numeric.

```
ggplot(data=stacked, aes( x = xaxis,  y=as.numeric(as.character(data)), colour=description))   +   geom_line()
```

You are making dataframe hardway. I cleaned a little bit.

```
a<-c(.493,.537,.50,.462)
b<-c(.846,-.117,-.349,-.385)
c<-c(-.181,.0657,.135,-.719)
d<-c(-.09,.51,-.77,.34)

data<-c(a,b,c,d)
description<-rep(c("PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4"), each=4)
ax <- rep(cbind(seq(from= 1, to = 4, by =1)), 4  )
stacked <- data.frame(data, description, xaxis= ax)  
ggplot(data=stacked, aes( x = xaxis,  y=data, colour=description))+geom_line()
```